# Stop a python thread from destructor

Tags: python, multithreading

I am somewhat new to Python programming. I am trying to make a script which will continously read a USB device in a separate thread (as this class will be imported into some GUI apps) using a dll, If there are any data it will call the callback function.

My problem is I want to stop the thread using the destructor and I am not sure about other better design to do it? Could any body please point me out if there are better methods?

My design is planned where my class can be imported and then, call the run through start, once the last object is destroyed the thread stops.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import ctypes
import threading
import time

USB_VENDOR_ID  = 0x23ef
USB_PRODUCT_ID = 0x0001

class usb_dev_comm(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, callback_fun):
        self.hidDll = ctypes.WinDLL("AtUsbHid.dll")
        self.usb_dev_connected = 0
        self.usb_stopall = 0
        self.callback = callback_fun
        return

    def usb_dev_present(self):
        self.res = self.hidDll.findHidDevice(USB_VENDOR_ID, USB_PRODUCT_ID)
        if (self.res == True):
            self.usb_dev_connected = 1
        else:
            self.usb_dev_connected = 0
        return self.res

    def usb_dev_tx(self,data):
        self.res = self.hidDll.writeData(data)
        return self.res

    def usb_dev_rx(self):
        data = 0
        result = self.hidDll.readData(data)
        if (result == False):
            return False
        else:
            return data

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            self.usb_dev_present()
            print self.usb_dev_connected
            if(self.usb_dev_connected):
                data_rx = self.usb_dev_rx()
                print data_rx
            #time.sleep(0.001)
            time.sleep(1)

    def __del__(self):
        print "del:cleanup required"
        #TODO


if __name__ == "__main__":
    def data_print(data):
        print data

    device = usb_dev_comm(data_print)
    result = device.run()
    print result
    print device.usb_dev_connected
```

I tried introducing

```
    def run(self):
        while self.stop_thread:
            self.usb_dev_present()
            print self.usb_dev_connected
            if(self.usb_dev_connected):
                data_rx = self.usb_dev_rx()
                print data_rx
            #time.sleep(0.001)
            time.sleep(1)

    def __del__(self):
        self.stop_thread = 1
        print "del:cleanup required"
        #TODO
```

But this is not working as I think this leads to chicken and egg problem

Comment: I highly discourage you from doing important stuff in destructor

Comment: @traceur so should i use something like a stop?